# Saving attribute field comments when making memory layer permanent in QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, fields-attributes, export

My QGIS plugin creates a vector layer (memory) with attribute fields that include comments. Comments are not saved when I "Make Permanent" the layer.

I have been able to build a QGIS Python plugin that creates a new line vector layer in memory and assigns various attribute fields that include explanatory comments for each field. So far so good. My problem arises when I save the memory layer using 'Make Permanent' (or even just close and reopen QGIS). The comments are not saved in the process.

[image: memory layer field that include comments]

While admittedly I haven't tried every format, when I save with GeoPackage for example, the comments disappear.

[image: 'Make Permanent' and save memory layer to file]

[image: field comments disappear after saving the layer to file]

How can I retain the comments permanently?

Comment: While not a direct answer to my question (how to preserve comments through the 'Make Permanent' process) I have discovered a nice work around for the time being. There is a plugin called Memory Layer Saver by Chris Cook. This works really nicely and preserves the comments through a saving / reopening of a QGIS project. Hats off to the author.

Comment: Oops. Chris Crook - apologies.

Comment: Just installed new release candidate 3.32 Lima. Comments are now preserved Making Permanent to GeoPackage format. Comments are still not preserved Making Permanent to ESRI Shapefile format.